# Prototyping for Amazon EC2

Tags: testing, amazon-ec2, synchronization, setup-deployment, prototyping

I wonder how people are prototyping for EC2.

In my case i want to code locally in my preferred editor and sync to a test instance and debug there, is this common practice? (vi/vim over ssh is not an option)

If so, are there any tools to sync code locally with a test instance other than rsync/sftp, anything automated?

If not, what are the options?

Any tips/walkthrough of how your code/debug cycle for EC2 looks like (pre commit), are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

My preferred setup is to

- Code on a local machine
- Check into version control
- Use continuous automation to get the checkins to version control and create a build
- Push the build result to a QA (or prototyping in your case) instance on EC2 (I used Maven, you could use FTP or rsync).
- When the QA (or prototyping) box is doing what you want, create an AMI of it.  Use that AMI to launch production instances.

Comment: the thing i'm concerned about is pushing code to version control that is not debugged. i'm used to only commit code that does compile. so you go through a clean-up of your commits at the end of each coding session (typos, etc)?

Comment: You debug on your local box.  You're also making sure the code passes unit tests on your local box (you have unit tests, right?).  A build server will fail if the unit tests don't pass, so won't push code any further.

Comment: what if i can't build on my local box due to requirements or i'm coding torwards a different plattform?

Comment: How do you test your code on the local box if you can't build there?  If you are e.g. doing Java development on Windows and deploying to Linux that's not a problem at all.

Comment: that's my point, i want to write code locally, sync to an ec2 instance & debug/test/build on it.

Comment: If you use git there's no reason you couldn't setup your test instance as a separate remote, so you could push there without pushing to your main repo. You can rebase/edit as needed before pushing to your main repo. And you can of course have your own little branch

Comment: Thanks Frederik, i guess i'll stick with that.

Answer (score 1):

Revision control is your friend.  Make you local code changes, submit them to your revision control server, then pull the changes into you amazon instance.